# How do I scale an image to be the same size as the paragraph?

Tags: html, css

How do I scale an image to be the same size as the paragraph?
[Like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M2Ar.png)

[This is how my site looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8b2x.png)

This is my code so far both Html and CSS

**CSS AND HTML**

```css
.paragraphers
{
    
    padding-left: 250px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}

.pix 
{  
    float: right;'
    width: 100px;
    height:20px;
    padding-right: 250px;
}
```

```html
   <div class = paragraphers>
     <p class = paragraphers>
         "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
     </div>
     
    
    
   <div class = pix>
       
     <img src = "images/stocktests/stock.jpg" id = pix>
     
     
     </div>
       
    
    
    </body>





</html>
```

Comment: what output actually you expect ?  in your html code where your <p> tag ends ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try grid system. Here the CSS :

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
}
  
.grid-container > div {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
}
  
.item1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
}

p {
      padding: auto 100px;
}
```

and HTML :

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">                
        <p style="font-size: 20px">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt officia autem quas architecto deleniti nisi reiciendis distinctio, nihil necessitatibus! Corporis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
        <img src = "coffee.jpg" style="width: 900px; height: 300px">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Try that one, i hope you found this helpfull